# How to correctly inject one select to other select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a working query which returns the average

```
SELECT r.client_id, r.mcc, r.mnc, r.rate, (max(r.rate) + min(r.rate)) / 2 As average 
FROM messages m
INNER JOIN rates r 
on m.rate_id = r.id
GROUP BY r.client_id
```

it works pretty good

but i need to get "average" in here:

```
...FROM (
      SELECT
        m.r_account_id,
        c.mcc,
        c.mnc,
        SUM(1)        AS total
        -- Average // i need to get value in here!!!
      FROM
        messages AS m

      JOIN
        costs AS c ON (
          c.id = m.cost_id
        )



JOIN
rates AS r ON (
r.id = m.rate_id
)



      WHERE
        m.create_timestamp BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(:date_from/1000) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(:date_to/1000)
      GROUP BY
        r_account_id,
        mcc,
        mnc
    ) AS s1
```

**this group should be :
 GROUP BY
        client_account_id,
        mcc,
        mnc**

but when i type like this :
GROUP BY
  client_account_id,
I can calculate avarage
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUcL5.png)

Help please

Comment: Do you want average from `rates` table? If yes then why are you not using it in join. Also do you want average as `max` + `min` / `2` or using average aggregate function. 

It is difficult to understand it from the code you gave. You need to give some sample data and your expected output based on that.

Comment: Then you need to `JOIN` **Rates** table as you did in first query

Comment: @MotoGP, i added pic

Comment: I think, i have to make other group BY for my task = / but dunno where